# jQuery UI Draggable with grid and containment has weird offset

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

#### Situation

I am trying to create a slider bar on my own instead of using jQuery `slider` widget.
However, I found that while using jQuery `draggable` widget, it created a weird offset on the left every time I clicked the handle inside the slider. And the handle had no way to get back to original position.
Is this situation related to the CSS box module? Or is there another reason that causes this problem?
 How can I fix it?

#### Code

Here's my code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBTM5/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  `css` line causing is the problem:

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

solution : [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/GFGc7/)

I'm not sure what the reason is behind it though :/

Comment: Thanks! I think it might be the problem with the bound of the handle after it rotate?

Comment: yw, yes it probably has to do with that, but to be sure you'll have to go through all the relevant css(in dev tools) to pinpoint the cause.